# Pb installig winehq on 20.04 (focal)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, wine, dependencies

Following the instructions from *wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu*, I removed all traces of a previous version of wine (the apt key, all programs and associated programs, all previous references to repositories). I added the new repository for version 20.04, its key and enabled the 32-bit architecture. I ran *apt update*.

winhq-stable refuses to install, complaining about an unresolved dependency of wine-stable. The latter refuses to install, complaining of an unresolved dependency of wine-stable-i386. The installation of wine-stable-i386 complains of eight unresolved dependencies:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libfontconfig1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: libgnutls30:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libgnutls28:i386 but it is not installable or
                                     libgnutls26:i386 but it is not installable
```

In the case of winhq-devel, the pattern is the same, the list for wine-devel-i386
is a bit shorter (only the last five direct dependencies).

I did some research, on this site (*askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wine+20.04*) and others;
I found similar questions (less detailed), but **NO PROPOSED SOLUTION**.

I've tried to resolve the dependencies of *-i386 packages, but it seems to be endless...
At some level, *sudo apt --fix-broken install* offers more destructive than constructive solutions
and do not (as far as I have tried) lead to a positive outcome.

If no one knows the answer, I will try first an upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish).(Translated from french with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator))

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've found `aptitude install` to provide more helpful error messages, maybe try it?

Comment: Unless you have a specific requirement for the latest wine version, undo all that you have done and install the version from the Ubuntu repos (currently 5.0-3ubuntu1)

Comment: "*I found similar questions (less detailed), but NO PROPOSED SOLUTION.*" suggests that you perhaps used the wrong search terms. The problem is that you are trying to bolt new software onto an old release of Ubuntu; as you have discovered that rarely works due to dependency version mismatches. The usual solutions are to use an appropriate older release of wine or to use a newer release of Ubuntu.